# NPM task runner

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm trying to make my own projects development tool using serveral NPM packages and running them via CLI configured in package.json. The last functionality I need to achieve is to watch specific directory for changes in my project folder and run specified task (like 'npm run compress-svg'). For example, in my project is svg folder, I need to watch that folder for changes and run npm task 'npm run compress-svg' when the folder changes. How can I achieve that functionality (maybe using another NPM package)?

Comment: [Grunt](https://gruntjs.com/), [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/), [Broccoli](http://broccolijs.com/), [Brunch](http://brunch.io/), ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`watch`](https://github.com/mikeal/watch) (`npm i watch --save-dev`) you could add a script into your npm.

```
"watch": "watch \"npm run compress-svg\" ./svg-folder"
```

I'm not too sure about the syntax of the command, it might need some testing/feedling.

But after you've found the correct syntax, you'll just have to run `npm run watch` and that's it.

You also have [`npm-watch`](https://github.com/M-Zuber/npm-watch) which seems easier to setup for you.